# MSYS2 MinGW x64 shell in Visual Studio Code opens up in new window

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, msys2

I want to integrate MSYS2 MinGW x64 shell as a terminal in Visual Studio Code.
I have followed these instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles). I can now launch a MSYS2 MinGW x64 shell from inside Visual Studio, but it pops up in a new window.
But I want to have it under the editor pane.

Here is my settings.json file:

```
{
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
"codetogether.userName": "Florian",
"git.autofetch": true,
"codetogether.allowUnauthorizedCerts": true,
"haskell.manageHLS": "GHCup",
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
        "path": [
            "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
            "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
        ],
        "args": [],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },
    "Git Bash": {
        "source": "Git Bash"
    },
    "MSYS2 MinGW x64": {
        "path": "D:\\Software\\MSYS2\\msys2_shell.cmd",
        "args": []
    }
}
```

}

What do I need to change here?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem, by replacing

```
"MSYS2 MinGW x64": {
        "path": "D:\\Software\\MSYS2\\msys2_shell.cmd",
        "args": []
    }
```

with

```
"MSYS2 MinGW x64": {
        "path": "D:\\Software\\MSYS2\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe",
        "args": []
    }
```

in my settings.json file.

Comment: You also might want to set the env variable `MSYSTEM` to `MINGW64` for this terminal. Otherwise you'll be opening the `MSYS` shell instead, which doesn't have the proper compiler in PATH.